# change word boundary intellij

Tags: android-studio, intellij-idea, intellij-14

Is there any way to change the word boundary in IntelliJ so that when I use the "move caret to next word" command, punctuation is ignored? (ie brackets periods quotations etc. etc.) Every time I look this up all I seem to find is tutorials on how to write Regex. Which I can see why that would be useful here, but where do I actually change the regex that defines word boundary?

Example, step by step:

current functionality:

1. |foo.bar
2. foo|.bar
3. foo.|bar
4. foo.bar|

desired functionality:

1. |foo.bar
2. foo.|bar
3. foo.bar|

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To the best of my knowledge, there is no setting to modify this behavior. A search of the IntelliJ IDEA source code,as detailed below,  seems to confirm this. To get the behavior you desire, you'll need to either [open a feature request](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues), or write a plug-in to do it.

**From the [Source Code](https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-community):**

The "Move Caret to the next word" action is done via the [NextWordAction](https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-community/blob/10a4c91dbfca935b4b5531003fd8c13b56e66202/platform/platform-impl/src/com/intellij/openapi/editor/actions/NextWordAction.java) class.That action uses the [NextPrevWordHandler](https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-community/blob/10a4c91dbfca935b4b5531003fd8c13b56e66202/platform/platform-impl/src/com/intellij/openapi/editor/actions/NextPrevWordHandler.java) to do the work. `NextPrevWordHandler` only has three boolean options:

1. next
2. withSelection
3. inDifferentHumpMode

These booleans are set in different permutations for the various actions that use this handler:

- NextWordAction
- NextWordInDifferentHumpsModeAction
- NextWordInDifferentHumpsModeWithSelectionAction
- NextWordWithSelectionAction
- PreviousWordAction
- PreviousWordInDifferentHumpsModeAction
- PreviousWordInDifferentHumpsModeWithSelectionAction
- PreviousWordWithSelectionAction

The `NextPrevWordHandler` in turn calls `EditorActionUtil.moveCaretToNextWord(...)`. Likewise, it does not take, or reference, any sort of word boundary setting. Thus there does not appear to be a way to modify the behavior to do what you desire.

Comment: Damn, that is what I feared. Thanks anyway Mark, I guess it is time to open a feature request. *sigh*

Comment: I opened ticket https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-206905 for a similar request